# Azure AD Stuck in a loop after Sign In

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am trying to integrate Azure AD for Authenticating access to a Web Application developed in ASP .NET Core and hosted on Azure.

I have added the TenantId, ClientId, and Domain to my appsettings.json.
I have also configured the middleware in the start up as follows:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions => {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
            .AddCookie()
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"])) 
                };
            });
```

The whole Web App is HTTPS.

The current behaviour is as follows:
1) Go to Site Home Page.

2) Access Resource that requires authorisation

3) Azure AD log in screen is displayed and login info is accepted

4) The page goes to white gets stuck in a redirect loop between my Web APP and the MS login site

[Request Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGA0O.png)

I saw in another question on SO that user's issue was related to sending cookies over HTTP vs HTTPS. However, that doesn't seem to be the case here. I tried to configure the middleware as follows (for testing purposes only) but the problem remains:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions => {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
            .AddCookie(options => {
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.None;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"])) 
                };
            });
```

Comment: If the auth flow is looping, my guess would be that the middleware is rejecting or otherwise not happy with the response it is getting from AAD. There isn't enough here to be able to give an answer, but you might try running your code under debugger with 'Just My Code' disabled, so that you can catch exceptions in the middleware. Also, try to examine the request your app makes when it 302's to AAD for the second time.

Comment: Another thought: try disabling all of the cookie options and see if the auth flow works. Cookie validation could be rejecting the redirect from AAD to your app.

Comment: It would also help if you posted the Controller code (specifically how authorization is configured). This post may help too: https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2

Comment: Why are you hard-coding the signing key for bearer tokens? Doesn't your idp offer a metadata endpoint for getting the public keys? Azure AD offers one for example.

Comment: @RyanS Thank you for the suggestions. It's not possible to use AAD without cookie auth enabled as far as I know.

Comment: @juunas That's a private signing key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the problem. I had initially setup my own identity service also using cookies. Removing the following code from the startup.cs solved the issue:

```
services.AddIdentity<ServiceUser, IdentityRole>(cfg => {
            cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });
```

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted out.